# What english verb is used in the most phrasal verbs

Tags: phrasal-verbs

This is just for fun. I've recently learned about phrasal verbs.

I'm interested in a total count of actual phrasal verbs for a given base verb. For example, "throw" is used in the formation of "throw up", "throw out", and "throw in", for a count of 3 (maybe there are more I'm missing).

If you think this question doesn't belong here, I apologize. Let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: Probably “get” is the verb most present in phrasal verbs. https://7esl.com/phrasal-verbs-with-get/#Phrasal_Verbs_with_GET

Comment: Certainly it's common enough, since _get_ is a general inchoative for both _be_ and _have_, and appears in many of their idioms. It's a good place to start, anyway. Here's [a handout](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/ParticlesInPhrasalVerbs.pdf) that contains lists of particles, verbs, and constructions -- with many idioms -- from a talk by Haj Ross.